# index statement code | ms-access and vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

i have problem with my code (ms-access and vb.net) :
i want to use this code :

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
    Try
        Dim indx As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(DataGridView1(1,e.RowIndex).Value)
```

in this case :

```
Private Sub FlatButton4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FlatButton4.Click
    Try
        Dim indx As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(DataGridView1(1,e.RowIndex).Value)
```

but i have a error in : [e.RowIndex]

how to resolve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see, in the `Click` event handler of your button, `e` is type `EventArgs` while in the `CellClick` event handler of the `DataGridView` it is type `DataGridViewCellEventArgs`.  It makes sense that `RowIndex` would be a member of that second type, which is specific to a `DataGridView`, while not of the first type, which knows nothing about the grid.

If what you want is to access a cell in the currently selected row then use this:

```
Dim indx As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value)
```